# Partial fraction expansion of $1/(e^x-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-fractions

I'm reading a paper by Riesel and Gohl; in it they say that "partial fraction expansion" of $1/(e^x-1)$ is
$$\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}+2x \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+4\pi^2k^2}$$
I tried using Euler's formula as $2\pi k$ are the roots of sine, but it leads nowhere. As the only root of $e^x-1$ is at $x=0$ and I fail to see how I can get this result with partial fractions. The Taylor expansion gives the first two terms correctly, but the rest is a power series involving  Bernoulli numbers. So ho do I use partial fractions to expand $1/(e^x-1)$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ as a meromorphic function on the complex plane and apply the residue theorem. $f(z)$ has simple poles for $z\in 2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: One thing this seems to leave out is how one gets the constant $1/2$ term. Taking the limit of $f(z)-1/z$ as $z\to 0$ works, but I'm forgetting if there's a slicker way.

Comment: @Semiclassical: maybe exploiting the fact that $\frac{x}{e^x-1}+\frac{x}{2}$ is an even function - in general, this is used to show that all the Bernoulli numbers with odd index, except $B_1=-1/2$, are zero.

Comment: That's a nice idea. A simple application of that: $$\frac{1}{2}(f(z)+f(-z))=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{e^z-1}+\frac{1}{e^{-z}-1}]=-1/2.$$ So the even part is just a constant term. (Can't figure out why that Mathjax isn't displaying in comments.)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I don't have much experience in complex analysis. Could you detail your answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

$~\quad~$ Alternately, start by differentiating the natural logarithm of Euler's infinite product for the sine function, and then use the well-known relations between hyperbolic and trigonometric functions to establish the desired result.

Comment: Did you mean the hyperbolic sine $\sinh(x)=x \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{x^2}{\pi^2k^2} \right)$? Because if I use $\sin(x)=x \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2k^2} \right)$, sign in summand is negative.

Comment: After differentiating $\ln \sinh (x)$ and setting $x \rightarrow x/2$ I get 
$\frac{\cosh(x/2)}{\sinh(x/2)}=\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}+\frac{1}{e^x-1}=2/x+4x \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (x^2+4\pi^2 k^2)^{-1}$. After this I'm stuck

Comment: @Nabigh: Concerning your first comment, we have $\sin x=-i\sinh ix$, which follows from [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula). As regards your second observation, all that's left to do now is proving that the two expressions for the value of our infinite series are equivalent, which is trivial. We have $a=b+c~S$ and $A=B+C~S$, which implies $\dfrac{a-b}c=\dfrac{A-B}C~$